# JavaScript text-based pet game

Tags: javascript, function, properties, constructor

I am trying to create a text-based virtual pet care game. I want to be able to give you two pets(Objects with properties) and functions to interact with those objects by modifying the objects properties. So here is what I have:

```
function Pet(pet_name){
    this.pet_name = pet_name;
    this.pet_hunger = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    this.pet_health = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    this.pet_happiness = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    this.feed = feed;
    this.show = show;
}

pet1 = new Pet("Brian");
pet2 = new Pet("Lassy");

function feed(){
    var amount = Math.floor((Math.random() *2) + 1);
    this.pet_hunger = this.pet_hunger - amount;
    if (this.pet_hunger < 0){
        this.pet_hunger = 0;
    }
    this.show();
 }

function show(){
    var the_string = "";
    if (this.pet_health === 0){
        the_string = this.pet_name + " is dead!";
    }
    else {
        the_string += "Name: " + this.pet_name;
        the_string += "Hunger: " + this.pet_name;
        the_string += "Health: " + this.pet_health;
        the_string += "Happiness: " + this.pet_happinesss;
    }
}
```

When I run the code:

```
console.log(pet1);
console.log(pet1.feed());  
console.log(pet1);
```

I receive the following:

```
{ pet_name: 'Brian',
  pet_hunger: 4,
  pet_health: 4,
  pet_happiness: 10,
  feed: [Function: feed],
  show: [Function: show] }
undefined
{ pet_name: 'Brian',
  pet_hunger: 2,
  pet_health: 4,
  pet_happiness: 10,
  feed: [Function: feed],
  show: [Function: show] }
```

So we can see the `feed` function is working. However, I'm still unsure why the undefined shows. Now, I created a function called `show`. This SHOULD show the four man stats(name, hunger, health, happiness) neatly. However, when I try to run:

```
console.log(pet1.show);
console.log(pet1.feed());
console.log(pet1);
```

I receive the following:

```
[Function: show]
undefined
{ pet_name: 'Brian',
  pet_hunger: 4,
  pet_health: 1,
  pet_happiness: 9,
  feed: [Function: feed],
  show: [Function: show] }
```

I'm unsure why my `show` function is not working. I really just want my console to show cleanly: Name: Hunger: Health: Happiness: Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the `undefined`s because, when you execute the code, the browser will log the return value of the functions. Since you aren't specifying a `return`, the functions return `undefined`, and that's what the console logs.

If you want to return that string in your `show` function, you'll have to... well, return the string:

```
// ...

function feed(){
    var amount = Math.floor((Math.random() *2) + 1);
    this.pet_hunger = this.pet_hunger - amount;
    if (this.pet_hunger < 0){
        this.pet_hunger = 0;
    }
    return this.show();
}

function show(){
    var the_string = "";
    if (this.pet_health === 0){
        the_string = this.pet_name + " is dead!";
    }
    else {
        the_string += "Name: " + this.pet_name + ", ";
        the_string += "Hunger: " + this.pet_hunger + ", ";
        the_string += "Health: " + this.pet_health + ", ";
        the_string += "Happiness: " + this.pet_happiness;
    }
    return the_string;
}

console.log(pet1.show()); 
// Logs 'Name: a, Hunger: b, Health: c, Happiness: d'
```

You also had some typos (before correction, your pet's happiness was `undefined`, ha), so I corrected them, and separated each property in the string with a comma, you can change that.

Comment: OH man, completely forgot about the `return`. So I was able to adjust it and now it works as intended. However, one problem I'm seeing is when trying to `return show` when running the `feed` method. I've tried to run: this.show; return show(); return show; and I cant seem to get the results of `feed` displayed in the `show` format that I have. I hope that makes sense. Again, thank you for your first response.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, that makes sense. All you have to do is change `this.show();` to `return this.show()` in your `feed` function. Check the update.

Comment: I had tried that and it didn't work, but it was because I left off the `( )` >.< Once again, good catch and thank you for the help.

Comment: Aaah, haha, stuff like that happens. No problem! Good luck with your game.